# How to handle a special Neumann-like boundary condition in NDSolve?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

How to solve the following nonlinear ODE with two algebraic equations and one  boundary condition?

$$y''(x)=\dfrac{2\left((x+15)y'(x)-y(x)\right)\left(y'(x)^2+1\right)}{\left(y(x)^2+x(x+30)+236\right)^2}$$

The Dirichlet boundary condition:
$$y(-14)=0$$

The Neumann-like boundary condition with a parameter $x_0$ undetermined:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 y(x_0)=\sqrt{1-x_0^2} &\\[15pt]
 y'(x_0)=\dfrac{-x_0}{\sqrt{1-x_0^2}}& \text{where: }-1\lt x_0\lt 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

The problem has a physical background in elementary geometric optics therefore the existence and uniqueness of the solution can be easily verified.

Closed form solution might be difficult to obtain. How can `NDSolve` handle such a boundary-like constraints? `Shooting` method? Solution domain should therefore be $[-14,x_0]$

In the tutorial document on `NDSolve`, there is one example on [`Boundary Value Problems with Parameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html), which converts the parameter-contained differential equation into an ODE system by introducing the parameter as a new dependent variable while keeping its first order derivative as zero:

```
Block[{R = 1}, 
 sol = NDSolve[{f'''[t] - R ((f'[t])^2 - f[t] f''[t]) + R a[t] == 0, 
    a'[t] == 0, f[0] == f'[0] == f'[1] == 0, f[1] == 1}, {f, a}, t];
 Column[{Plot[f[t] /. First[sol], {t, 0, 1}],
   a[0] /. First[sol]}]]
```

But the method does not solve this problem with a parameter in the boundary conditions instead. How to solve it similarly?

It seems `ParametricNDSolve` does not handle such problems.

**Update**

I update this only want to learn the mathematica grammar from @xzczd

If I change the same problem into the following form, i.e. there are parameters in both the left and right boundary conditions of the same nonliear ODE:

left boundary:

$$y(x_l)=-\sqrt{1-(x_l+15)^2},y'(x_l)=\dfrac{x_l+15}{\sqrt{-(x_l+14)(x_l+16)}},\quad -15<x_l<-14$$

right boundary:

$$y(x_r)=\sqrt{9-x_r^2},\quad,y'(x_r)=\dfrac{-x_r}{\sqrt{9-x_r^2}},\quad -3<x_r<0$$

Then how will you rewrite the code per your programming style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat surprising that `ParametricNDSolve` can't handle this type of parameter. Alright, let's go back to the old-fashioned `_?NumericQ`:

```
eqn = y''[x] == (2 ((x + 15) y'[x] - y[x]) (y'[x]^2 + 1))/(y[x]^2 + x (x + 30) + 236)^2;

bcl = y[-14] == 0;

bcr = {y[x0] == Sqrt[1 - x0^2], y'[x0] == -x0/Sqrt[1 - x0^2]};

f[sol_, bcr_] := (sol[Pattern[#, _]?NumericQ] := 
                    NDSolveValue[{eqn, bcl, bcr}, y, {x, -14, 0}]) &@x0

MapThread[f, {{sol1, sol2}, bcr}];

FindRoot[sol1[x0][x0] == sol2[x0][x0], {x0, -1/2, -1, 0}]
Plot[sol1[x0][x] /. % // Evaluate, {x, -14, 0}]
```

> ```
> {x0 -> -0.0716993}
> ```

[image]

---

**Response to the new added question**

The idea is the same:

```
eqn = y''[x] == (2 ((x + 15) y'[x] - y[x]) (y'[x]^2 + 1))/(y[x]^2 + x (x + 30) + 236)^2;
bcl = {y[xl] == -Sqrt[1 - (xl + 15)^2], y'[xl] == (xl + 15)/Sqrt[-(xl + 14) (xl + 16)]};
bcr = {Sqrt[9 - xr^2], -xr/Sqrt[9 - xr^2]};

(solL[Pattern[#, _]?NumericQ] := NDSolveValue[{eqn, #2}, y, {x, -15, 0}]) &[xl, bcl]

FindRoot[{solL[xl][xr], solL[xl]'[xr]} == bcr, {{xl, -29/2, -15, -14}, {xr, -3/2, -3, 0}}]
```

> ```
> {xl -> -14.7652, xr -> -0.816397}
> ```

Comment: thank you! I am actually shocked by the grammer style you are using, e.g., when define the function `f`; how do you know mathematica allows such definitions (with `:= ` `:=`)? I want to learn its details very much. If both the left and right boundary conditions have a parameter $x_{\text{left}},x_\text{right}$ to be determined, how do you rewrite it? Why you use `MapThread` in this case to define the `sol1` and `sol2`? what is the advantage? Why in the `FindRoot` sentence, there are two brackets with $x_0$s ? The codes work, but I don't know why. I tried to program it similary but failed.

Comment: @LCFactorization `f` is just a function that creates function. I create this function for conciseness. These 2 lines can be replaced by `sol1[x0_?NumericQ] := NDSolveValue[{eqn, bcl, bcr[[1]]}, y, {x, -14, 0}]; sol2[x0_?NumericQ] := NDSolveValue[{eqn, bcl, bcr[[2]]}, y, {x, -14, 0}];`, now it's a little easier to understand, right?

Comment: yes, thanks, it is now clearer for these two lines. why you define two `sol1` `sol2`? Why `FindRoot[sol1[x0][x0] == sol1[x0][x0], {x0, -1/2, -1, 0}]` does not work? how to understand `sol1[x0][x0]`(there're two brackets, two arguments? why not simplified into one `xo` and how?)

Comment: I am still not very clear about the last two lines of the code, can you please add an additional code answer to the updated question with two undetermined parameters in both the left and the right boundary conditions? thank you. I understand the basic ideas of the algorithms, but when I tried to code the algorithm myself per my understanding on the Mathematica grammar, I only got a lot  error messages.

Comment: @LCFactorization See my edit. If you still have difficulty in understanding, evaluate `solL[14]` alone and check the output. Notice that precisely speaking, $x_0$ is not undetermined, but **to be** determined.

Comment: thank you very much! this time, only one `sol` defined, but I am again confused by a little `prime` symbol between the two arguments on the left side of the `FindRoot` equality, which does not seem to be a derivative symbol. Can you please explain this, why such a prime is necessary?  I will try to study the code and see whether I can rewrite it per my own understanding. BTW, if I want to learn such kind of `native` only-Mathematica-style grammar, do you have any recommendation on reading materials besides the tutorials and stackexchange.com?

Comment: @LCFactorization It's just derivative symbol, when `xL` gets a numeric value, `solL[xl]` will evaluate to a `InterpolatingFunction`. As to the reading material part, have you ever read Leonid Shifrin's excellent book? Here's the unfinished Chinese edition: http://tieba.baidu.com/p/3230448463

Comment: Thank you. Let me try to read it first. It seems the English version of the book is publicly available. I had never read it before. All the Mathematica programming knowledge I now have is by self-teaching and practices. Another question, can `solL[Pattern[#, _]?NumericQ]` be changed into `solL[#]` for simplication purpose?

Comment: BTW,yuan lai ni shi baidu Mathematica tie ba de ba zhu a ?

Comment: @LCFactorization `?NumericQ` is necessary to suppress the warning, if you don't mind the warning, simply use `solL[xl_]`. There're many examples for the usage of `?NumericQ` in this site, you can have a search.

Comment: The book you recommended is really what I need to read! Thank you! Very useful.